# Render a full entire html page from custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I've searched/asked around without success.

I'm creating a custom Drupal 7 module, and I would like to render the code in an empty full template (not a page/node.tpl.php); by full template I mean a template containing the `<html>` tag.

Since now, I've used the following code but the template is rendered in page.tpl.php (`render($page['content'])`).

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'adm_xyz' => array (
      'render element' => 'render',
      'template' => 'adm_xyz', //  template *.tpl.php
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your callback in [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) will by default call [drupal_deliver_html_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7) which in turn calls drupal_render_page() where the page.tpl.php comes from.

It is possible to implement your own "delivery callback" method, which will be called by [drupal_deliver_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_page/7) this is how the ajax is delivered in D7

Comment: Good answer. Still I am curious what could possibly go wrong if you simply print + exit() in the page callback?

Comment: Nothing else will be able to alter page structure. Late hooks will not get called.