# Create full page custom module

Tags: theming

I would like to create a full page with a custom module. I mean a page that should not reside within the larger Drupal page. How can I achieve this?

This is the code I am using.

#### mymodule.module

```
 function mymodule_menu() {
   $result = array();
   $result['mymodule'] = array(
     'title' => "Some Title",
     'page callback' => "mymodule_function",
     'access callback' => true,
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     'weight' => 1,
   );

   return $result;
}

function mymodule_function() {
  print theme('my_custom_template');
  exit; 
}   

function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_custom_template' => array(     
      'template' => 'mymodule-page',
    ),
  );
}
```

#### mymodule-page.tpl.php

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine enough, but is this the correct method?  I also wonder how I would include forms (submit data, retrieve data, display that data, etc)?

Comment: You are working with Drupal 7, I assume? Can you add the "7" tag?

Comment: Similar question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38576/page-which-display-only-content-no-header-footer-sidebars

Comment: Oh, actually this one has a good answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/render-a-full-entire-html-page-from-custom-module?rq=1 Use a custom page delivery callback!

Comment: Hello.  I've added Drupal 7 to my question.  I have looked at the the second suggestion, but as  I am new to this, I had a hard time following what was being discussed.  Do you have any example code?

Comment: Maybe you could further specify your use case: You say "it should not reside within the larger Drupal page". Why? You don't want the blocks, sidebar, header etc? What is the purpose of this page?

Comment: Hello, ultimately, I would like the drupal core site to manage things like users, roles, etc.  Then create individual web sites, within individual modules.  This way, I can manage multiple sites, each with its own design and layout, but all within the same environment.

Comment: Do you mean "sites" or "pages"? For me, one "site" can be multiple pages. If you want some pages of your website to have a different layout, consider different themes, or a different page templates.

Comment: This would be sites.  As in each site would be multiple pages

Comment: Ok, now I would propose different themes or different page templates. See e.g. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically for different themes.